# How do I get the class name from HTML using the absolute xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

In the following picture, the full xpath of the yellow highlighted bit of HTML is

/html/body/bx-site/ng-component/div/sp-sports-ui/div/main/div/section/main/sp-path-event/div/sp-next-events/div/div/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSuNU.png)/sp-coupon[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSuNU.png)/sp-multi-markets/section/section/sp-outcomes/sp-two-way-vertical[2]/ul/li[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSuNU.png)/sp-outcome/button

I am using selenium to scrape some data from a website. The text of the xpath is what I want but I also need the class name of the yellow highlight bit of HTML. The class name constantly changes so I need a way to retrieve the class name along with the text. In this case the class name would be "bet-btn". I am using driver.find_element_by_xpath to get the text from the html, but can't figure out a way to retrieve the class name. Using the xpath is there a way in selenium to retrieve the class name of the yellow highlighted bit.

[image: html code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against using absolute xpath unless you really needed to

Try this instead:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//sp-outcome/button")
class_value = elem.get_attribute("class")
```

BTW that `xpath` is assuming there are no other `//sp-outcome/button` element paths on that page. If there are you would need to expand it some, but you still wouldn't need the entire absolute `xpath`.  Those are generally pretty fragile.